# IndexError: list index out of range | webapp2

Tags: python, html, webapp2

I have the following code. It works fine but when the `players` list's length becomes 0, my web page becomes blank and this `IndexError: list index out of range` error appears in my terminal (server). I want a way to redirect the server into `self.redirect('/')` when the `players` list becomes empty.

```
def choose_random_player(list):
    return random.choice(list)


class GuessPlayer(Handler):
    players = ['sanchez', 'welbeck', 'giroud', 'ozil', 'ramsey']
    random_player = choose_random_player(players)
    score = 0

    def get(self):
        self.render("guessplayer.html",
                    random_player=GuessPlayer.random_player,
                    score=GuessPlayer.score)

    def post(self):
        user_answer = self.request.get("player-name")
        if user_answer == GuessPlayer.random_player:
            GuessPlayer.score += 1
            GuessPlayer.players.remove(GuessPlayer.random_player)
            GuessPlayer.random_player = choose_random_player(GuessPlayer.players)
            self.render("guessplayer.html",
                        random_player=GuessPlayer.random_player,
                        score=GuessPlayer.score)
        else:
            self.render("guessplayer.html",
                        random_player=GuessPlayer.random_player,
                        score=GuessPlayer.score)
```

The html form:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h4>Enter The Player Name</h4>
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="score">Score: {{score}}</div>
        <img src="../images/{{random_player}}.jpg" alt="...">
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="player-name">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: please add `choose_random_player` definition

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that when `players` is an empty list, `choose_random_player(players)` raises an `IndexError`.

You can catch this exception and redirect the user to `/` if you want, but it's a bit ugly.

```
def get(self):
    try:
        random_player = choose_random_player(players)
    except IndexError:
        self.redirect('/')

    self.render(...)
```

A more clean version would be to check if `players` is an empty list before choosing a random player.

```
def get(self):
    if len(players) == 0:
        self.redirect('/')

    random_player = choose_random_player(players)
    self.render(...)
```

You'd have to write similar checks in your `post` handler as well.

Comment: @h236a on what line?